# 複数NICがある Linux からの mysql 利用時のインターフェース固定方法について

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

複数NICがある Linux からの mysql 利用時のインターフェース固定方法についてご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら教えて頂けませんでしょうか？

ping だとオプション「I」を用いることで任意のNICからパケットを送ることができたのですが、mysql利用時も同様に任意のNICを用いるオプションなどありましたら教えていただけませんでしょうか？

【環境】
ubuntu16.04
NIC1 : 192.168.100.1
NIC2 : 192.168.200.1

MariaDB 10.0

＊参考図

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

追加画像
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

linux の ip rule 適用で無理やりルーティング変更しても(defaultルートは変更禁止)ダメでした。
pingのオプション I がやりたいことにマッチしており、実際にpingだとこちらが想定しているIPからの送信となっております。

Comment: すみません。自分の説明が下手くそでした。今、図を用いて修正させて頂きます。大変申し訳ございませんでした。

Comment: サーバーでNIC1なら`bind-address=192.168.100.1`。クライアントなら`--bind-address=192.168.100.1`みたいです

Comment: mysql: unknown variable 'bind-address=192.168.100.1'  と表示されてしまいました；

Comment: `mysql --bind-address-192.168.100.1 -u user -p db`という感じです。--つけてますか？

Comment: はい、unknown variableが出てしまいます。 --bind-address-192.168.100.1でも --bind-address=192.168.100.1でも出てしまいます。

Comment: MariaDB に付属の msql コマンドには `--bind-address` オプションは存在しません。

Comment: 試してないので 出切るかどうか 分からないですが 静的ルートを追加するのはどうですか？  `route add -host 192.168.300.1 gw 192.168.300.1 eth1` ←NIC2のインターフェースを指定

Comment: 192.168.100.1などだと通常/24ですがそれだと話が通りません。IPアドレスを実際の物か現実を反映した物にしてもらえませんか。

Comment: .300は.255を超えますからそんなIPはあり得ないということですね。 スタティックルートはデバイスだけ指定すれば良いのでは？`route add -host 192.168.3.1 eth1` ←使いたいネットワークがeth1だとする。

Comment: ipコマンドはダメでしたということなら、実際に叩いたコマンドを書いてください。`ip route add 192.168.3.1 dev eth1`で上のrouteコマンドと同じです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql コマンドの bind-address オプションは 5.6 からです。

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_bind-address

MariaDB については詳しくありませんが、MariaDB 10.0 は MySQL 5.5 ベースのようなので、bind-address オプションが無いのかもしれません。

MySQL と MariaDB のプロトコルに互換があるのであれば、クライアントは MariaDB ではなく MySQL の mysql コマンドを使うという方法もあるかもしれません。